# Net::Http The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, net-http

I'm using the [Bluepay](https://www.bluepay.com/) API to process payments in my Rails app. The following code is setting up a POST request to the server. `RootCA` is the path to the SSL certs; locally this is just set to '/'

```
ua = Net::HTTP.new(SERVER, 443)
ua.use_ssl = true

# Checks presence of CA certificate
if File.directory?(RootCA)
  ua.ca_path = RootCA
  ua.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
else
  puts "Invalid CA certificates directory. Exiting..."
  exit
end
```

This works fine locally after calling `ua.post(<args>)`. On Heroku however, the following error is returned:

```
400 Bad Request

The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

I have set the SSL certificate path to "/usr/lib/ssl/certs/" as instructed in this [Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-path-to-the-SSL-root-certificate-trusted-root-CA-on-Heroku), but I'm still getting an error.

Comment: Are you using Heroku on a paid dyno or free?

Comment: Paid Hobby dyno at $7 per month.